# sharepoint 2016 server down with all progress

Tags: disaster-recovery

I have development SharePoint 2016 farm with 2 servers one SharePoint and one SQL server 2014, SharePoint server is lost and infra team cannot restore it, I have content database can i restore it in new sharepoint farm and what the best solution for that case especially that all my progress in that server and deployed solutions and 2 portals were in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have backup of the content database, you can attach it to the brand new SharePoint farm with no problem (just make sure it has the same build number and all required managed paths are in place).
You can do it by specifying database name in *CA - Web Applications - Manage Content Databases - Add content database* or using [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/mount-spcontentdatabase?view=sharepoint-server-ps). More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/attach-or-detach-content-databases).

But it won't restore your whole custom solution, because solution files are usually stored in SharePoint folder (*Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions*) on SP server.
Therefore, after attaching, you will have errors about orphaned features in DB and so on (you can also check them by [Test-SPContentDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/test-spcontentdatabase?view=sharepoint-server-ps)).

So, anyway, you should have your solution package file or source code to restore your solution completely.